# Seeking a basic Google Analytics dashboard

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics and it's proving to be incredibly unwieldy for my basic needs. The only metrics I want displayed are "Recent Pageloads" formatted like so:

**Data** | **Time** | **System** | **Location** | **Host** | **Length of Visit**

That's it.

However, Google Analytics appears to have a steep learning curve where this basic visualization appears rather difficult to create. Is there a default dashboard I could implement? or can someone direct me to create a dashboard with just these fields?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible to create a dashboard. In the image below you can see where you're able to find the dashboard. From there on you can create a new widget. I believe the widget you want to create are with metric 'pageviews'. If you choose the table layout you can see how it correlates to a dimension ie for instance location. [image: Image of dashboard location]